Old trilogy about God watching the fractal universe while mankind suffered
This was a series of a few novels I read maybe 20-30 years ago. I seem to remember maybe an Australian author, but that could be wrong.
The stories focused around the Fallen Angel and him living in the world trying to help relieve the suffering of man, while God sat remote, absorbed watching the beautiful fractal patterns of the universe created by the infinite stories and suffering of mankind.
It was in the future, technologically from now. The fallen angel's name was one of the "A" names... Azrael?
Azazel? Something like that.

not a trilogy but i'm reminded of "The Egg" by Andy Weir

Isaac Asimov wrote a series of short stories with a demon or e.t. named azazel.

Azazel is a character created by Isaac Asimov and featured in a series of fantasy short stories. Azazel is a two-centimeter-tall demon (or extraterrestrial), named after the Biblical demon.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azazel_(Asimov)

In the Hebrew Bible, the name Azazel (/əˈzeɪzəl, ˈæzəˌzɛl/; Hebrew: עֲזָאזֵל ʿĂzāʾzēl) represents a desolate place where a scapegoat bearing the sins of the Jews was sent during Yom Kippur. During the late Second Temple period (after the closure of the Hebrew Bible canon), Azazel came to be viewed as a fallen angel responsible for introducing humans to forbidden knowledge, as described in the Book of Enoch. His role as a fallen angel partly remains in Christian and Islamic traditions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azazel
Azazel has appeared in some books:

Robertson Davies introduces Azazel and Samahazai as rebel angels in the first book of his Cornish Trilogy, The Rebel Angels. They are said to have "betrayed the secrets of Heaven to King Solomon", so that "God threw them out of Heaven", and on earth "they taught tongues, and healing and laws and hygiene".
Azazel is the principal character in a series of short stories written by Isaac Asimov.
Azazel is a leader of the fallen angels in the light novel (and manga/anime) series High School DxD. He becomes a teacher and club advisor at their school.
In the light novel (and manga/anime) series Blue Exorcist Azazel is one of the eight Demon Kings and a son of Satan.
Azazello is a character in Mikhail Bulgakov's novel The Master and Margarita.4
In the fifth book of The Mortal Instruments, Azazel is a greater demon raised by warlock Magnus Bane to help in a search for shadowhunter Jace Lightwood.
Neil Gaiman's Sandman comics, published by DC Comics, features Azazel as a character.
The X-Men comic books features a mutant based on the legendary demon, created by writer Chuck Austen.

In José Saramago's book "Cain" Azazel is a God's cherub who lets Eve into the Garden of Eden after she and Adam had been expelled from it. Enchanted by Eve's naked body, he makes a secret deal with her and gets her fruits from the garden, as she and her husband were wandering hungry and with no means of survival after the expulsion.

In poem Moses by Ivan Franko, Azazel is a demon of the desert and is the main antagonist.
In Japanese Manga “Record of Ragnarok”shuumatsu no valkeryie by Ajichika, Shinya Umemura, Takumi Fukui he acts as a supporting character to Beelzebub as one of his first friends before being killed by Satan.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azazel_in_popular_culture
The description of Canadian author Robertson Davies's Cornish Trilogy published between 1981 and 1988 makes it seem like it might be the series you remember.
But the description here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cornish_Trilogy
Describes only the human characters and says nothing about demons.
So I hope this may be of some help in the search for a series of novels possibly involving a demon Azazel.

The Cornish Trilogy doesn't sound like a good match at all. These are basically standard literary novels without any real fantasy/sci-fi connection except the presence of supernatural demons as narrators. God is not involved, not set in the future.
